# Encoding uncompressed avi using RAWVIDEO codec and RGB24

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, encoder, avi

I coded an encoder using FFMPEG (c++). The requirements for this encoder are:

1. The output format should be uncompressed avi,
2. Preferably using RGB24/YUV444 pixel format since we do not want chroma subsampling.
3. Most standard players should support the format (windows media player (WMP), VLC)

Using the encoder I wrote, I can write a number of file types right now:

1. Lossless H.264 encoded video using the YUV420p pixel format and AVI container. (Obviously not uncompressed and chroma subsampled, however both WMP and VLC play without any problem.)
2. MPEG4 encoded video using the YUV420p pixel format and AVI container.(Obviously not uncompressed and chroma subsampled, however both WMP and VLC play without any problem.)
3. AYUV encoded video using the YUVA444P pixel format. (uncompressed as far as I understand and not chroma subsampled. However, VLC does not play this.)
4. FFV1 encoded video using the YUV444P pixel format. (lossless, and not chroma subsampled. However, WMP does not play this.)

The above is derived from [this very usefull post](https://superuser.com/questions/347433/how-to-create-an-uncompressed-avi-from-a-series-of-1000s-of-png-images-using-ff).

So I am now looking into the RAWVIDEO encoder from FFMPEG. I can't get this to work and neither can I find an example in the FFMPEG documentation on how to use this encoder for writing video. Can somebody point me in the right direction or supply sample code for this?
Also, if there is another direction I should follow to meet my requirements feel free to point me to it.

Thanks in advance